# Find $F'(x)$ if $F(x)=\int_0^x{\frac{1}{1+\sin^6{t}+t^2}}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

Could someone give me some insight or tips (not the solution) on how to find $F'(x)$ if
$$F(x)=\int_0^x{\frac{1}{1+\sin^6{t}+t^2}}dt$$

For some reason I cant wrap my head around this.

Comment: How to solve what? Possibly the exercise says something like: find $F'(x)$ if $$F(x) = \int_0^x{\frac{1}{1+\sin^6{t}+t^2}}dt.$$ Am I right?

Comment: exactly that, i've already modified the question. thanks for the observation.

Comment: Always make sure you have clearly and correctly transcribed and understood the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has formally submitted an answer and since you don't simply want a solution, I will simply refer you to the fundamental theorem of calculus.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Answer (score 1):

You can simply proceed by using a formula called the Newton-Leibnitz formula.
$$F'(x)=\frac{1}{1+\sin^6x+x^2}$$